# Cypress - error occurs when I installed 'del' module, cant open cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, cypress-configuration

I installed del module:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-spec-api#Delete-the-recorded-video-if-the-spec-passed

then I configured cypress config but this line:

```
const del = require('del')
```

makes that cypress is not working (I cant even select any browser):
[image]
[image]

When I commented out this line (const del = require('del')), cypress worked normally.

How can I fix it?

- Cypress version: 12.5
- del version: 7.0.0

Comment: That is definitely a bug! Go to the Cypress github account and lodge an issue, you will probably get a prize! (No not really).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of `del` v7.0.0 isn't compatible with the example code Cypress gives.

You could downgrade to v6.1.1 and the sample code will run.

```js
npm install del@6.1.1
```

I would remove ver 7.0.0 first to be sure you get the older version installed.

---

You can use ver 7.0.0 and alter the code to use [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import).

The newest version also changes the function names to `deleteAsync` and `deleteSync`, so the usage is slightly different.

Here's the changes to the Cypress sample code:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('after:spec', (spec, results) => {
        if (results && results.stats.failures === 0 && results.video) {
          return import('del').then(del => {
            return del.deleteSync(results.video)
          })
        }
      })
    },
  },
})
```